# Change Outlook's default email format when sending attachment from shell

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, format

When I right-click a file in Windows Explorer and select `Send To > Mail Recipient`, Outlook 2007 invariably sets the email format to Plain Text.

This is really freaking annoying and I can't find an option to change it.

How can I tell it to always use HTML format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234487) (KB 234487):

> To change the **Sendto** function to use
>   the Outlook default message format,
>   you need to create a shortcut in the
>   Send To folder that calls an Outlook
>   formatted message window.

Comment: /me bangs head against desk (edit - repeatedly)

Comment: I never said it was a **nice** way to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it via Account setting. Set the mail you prefer as default.

Outlook > File > Info > Choose email > Account Settings > Email Tab > Choose the preferred mail > Set a default